# Python summing values in a variable

Tags: python, list, variables, printing, sum

In python, I want to sum all of the values in a variable.

My code is

```
x=100
y=200
for i in range(a,b):
  if i%2==1:
    print(i)
```

When I print i, it lists all of the odd numbers from 100 to 200. But I want to sum it all. The answer should be 7500.

Comment: So, instead of printing `i`, add all `i`s and print the sum variable at the end?

Comment: ``sum(i for i in range(100, 200) if i % 2 == 1)`` ?

Comment: `sum(range(101, 200, 2))`

Comment: `(200 // 2) ** 2 - (100 // 2) ** 2`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this;

```
a=100
b=200
sum=0
for i in range(a,b):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        sum+=i
print(sum)
```

output:

```
7500
```